# Why can I now open the same file on 2 iMacs without it saying "read only'

Tags: imac, permission

My work colleague and I have an issue with file permissions since he upgraded his iMac. Basically, he stores the main files on his Mac, I then connect and can access his files. Before he got the upgraded Mac, if one of us had a file open, it would appear as "read only" to the other person - now it doesn't and it seems we can both access the file without this warning which is a disaster! I've tried messing about with all the permissions to no avail - can anybody help?

Comment: how are you connecting with each other. Do you AirDrop or you mean on Network ? Did you check File Permission?

Comment: @Udhy seems like they want to keep it so that only one person can open the file at one time, other sees it as read-only. This is not airdrop functionality. Sounds like corporate network sharing... Hazel, could you test with a test txt file and see if both are simultaneously allowed to edit it or not? It might prompt for making a duplicate while saving.. or maybe not. And as asked, what are the file permissions while normal and while one opens them?

Comment: So we are just connected wirelessly over the network. I created a .txt file on my machine, my colleague can then open it and edit it without it saying read only. He saves it, when I go to save mine it warns me that the file has been changed. I just want it to warn me of read only like it used to!